# Shadow catcher do not rendering in one specific project

Tags: rendering, shadowcatcher

I have a specific project in which shadows are not displayed when rendering with a shadow catcher, although in all other projects everything works fine

Its how shadow catcher looking on render mode in layout

[image: and there is a result on when i rendered it]

[image: and there is a result on when i rendered it]